# What determines an 'Abandoned cart' in CartThrob and PostMaster?

Tags: cartthrob, postmaster

I'm using [Postmaster](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/features) to send notifications on a 'Cartthrob Abandonded Cart' however I have no idea how to trigger an abandoned cart to test it.

Does anyone know what steps are involved? Or what tables are checked etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can set this up in Postmaster -> Notifications. Ensure that you choose the CartThrob Abandoned Cart notification type.

Just add something to the cart, but don't checkout. Ensure that the time interval is set for your notification. For testing i just added 15 into the minutes column to send me an email after 15 minutes.